# Initializing in arima.sim in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to simulate from an `ARMA(1,2)` series. I need to initialize `$X0$ = 9`. How do I do it in R? I cannot find any provision for initialization in `arima.sim`

Answer (score 4):

You may get it using the right combination of the arguments `start.innov`, `n.start` and `innov` that are passed to `stats:arima.sim`.

For an AR process with parameter `phi`, it is easy to see that the following yields the first simulated value equal to $X_0=9$.

```
n <- 50
phi <- 0.5
x0 <- 9
set.seed(123)
arima.sim(n, model=list(ar=phi), start.innov=x0/phi, n.start=1, 
  innov=c(0,rnorm(n-1)))
#  [1]  9.00000000  3.93952435  1.73958469  2.42850066  1.28475872  0.77166710
#  [7]  2.10089853  1.51136547 -0.50937850 -0.94154210 -0.91643302  0.76586529
# [13]  0.74274647  0.77214469  0.49675506 -0.30746361  1.63318133  1.31444115
# ...
```

For the ARMA(1,2) you should do the maths, for example I found the following combination 
for the parameters used below:

```
set.seed(123)
arima.sim(n=50, model=list(ar=0.5, ma=c(0.4, 0.2)), start.innov=c(0,0,10), 
  n.start=3, innov=c(rep(0,3),rnorm(47)))
#  [1]  9.00000000  6.50000000  3.25000000  1.06452435  0.07789443  1.39348940
#  [7]  1.34470092  1.14158321  2.35167337  2.34863643  0.43663646 -0.88237587
# [13] -1.41460329  0.20114479  0.86088655  1.21995661  0.95293237  0.04505243
# ...
```

Comment: I am interested in this answer. I wish you could private chat with me so I can ask you some question which I have been unable to understand but can not ask you here in order to keep the rule

Comment: @DanielJames I recommend you to make question in a new post here in stackoverflow or in [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). You may be interested in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127441/initialize-arp-process-by-using-arima-sim).

Comment: Is it possible to restrict time series to fall within the interval [L,U]?

Comment: @Katatonia I think it is not possible to enforce lower or upper bounds. The range of the data would depend partly on the standard deviation of the innovations. You may try setting e.g. `innov=c(rep(0,3),rnorm(47, sd=0.1)))` hoping for a narrower range. But overall, I don't see a way to make sure that the bounds are enforced. You should trim the data afterwards or follow another approach.